Is stitching and aligning two layers a proper use of QGIS?
I'm a beginner who hasn't used QGIS before but am excited at the possibilities.  I have an Esri World Topo and a tiff of an 18th century map.   I would like to have the older map align with the topo.   Years ago I subcontracted with BLM for a project and the software would allow me to identify a lighthouse on one map and then the same lighthouse on the other.   After 12 or so pairs of points were made the software would chew on it and then align the two, stretching when necessary.
Is such a feature available within QGIS or is that not the intended use?

You want the Georeferencer.  It is found in the menu Layer - Georeferencer.  It is worth checking out how to use the tool and what transformation options are available with it. https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html

The Georeferencer is what you use to do this.  Access it in the Layers -> Georeferencer... menu:

The tool will open in a new window.

Add your un-georeferenced image (the 18th century map) to the georeferencer tool and have the world topo in the main map window.

In the georeferencer, click "Add point" and select a point on the un-georeferenced image

In the little widow that appears that says "Enter Map Coordinates" click "From Map Canvas" and select the same point on the topo in the main map


There's more information in the help, but that should get you started.

Awesome!!  Thank you both.
